# A countably compact, locally connected space has finitely many components

Tags: general-topology

The question is to prove that a countably compact locally connected space $X$ has finitely many components.

My (incorrect) proof goes like this: Let $\{ B_i \}_{i = 1}^{\infty}$ be an open cover of $X$. Then $\{ C({B_i}) \}_{i=1}^{\infty}$ is also an open cover of $X$. Take $\{ C({B_i}_{k}) \}_{k=1}^{N}$. This clearly also covers $X$, so $X$ has finitely many components.

However, this fails if one of the $B_i$ has uncountably many infinite components. How can I fix the proof?

Comment: What is $C(B_i)$?

Comment: @Pedro The components of $X$ containing $B_i$

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT: You know that components are always closed; show that if $X$ is locally connected, they’re also open. If $X$ has infinitely many components, use this fact to get a countable open cover with no finite subcover.

Comment: So I argue that the countably infinitely many components are all open, and they cover $X$. Moreover, every $x \in X$ is in exactly one component, so any subcover would not cover $X$, contradicting countable compactness. That eliminates the countably infinite case, but if there are uncountably infinite components I can't do that, since I only have countable compactness. What can I do in that case?

Comment: @Johanna: Let $C_n$ ($n\in\Bbb Z^+$) be countably infinitely many components, and take the union of the other components as $C_0$.

Comment: I don't see how that would help me. I can't know that my finite subcover won't include $C_0$, and then I still have uncountably many components.

Comment: @Johanna: But that’s a cover by pairwise disjoint sets: it doesn’t *have* a finite subcover.

Comment: I see. I think I understand now. Thank you.

Comment: @Johanna: You’re welcome.