# Let $X$ be a locally path connected compact space. Show that $X$ has only finitely many path components.

Tags: general-topology, path-connected

> Let $X$ be a locally path connected compact space. Show that $X$ has only finitely many path components.

Since $X$ is locally path connected each point $x \in X$ has a neighborhood $U_x$ such that there exists path connected $V_x$ for which $x \in V_x \subset U_x$.

Since $X$ is compact any open cover has a finite subcover.

Now if we assume that $X$ had infinitely many path components, then I think I should be able to contradict compactness, but I cannot figure out a way to show this. I only now that the path components parition $X$, but there is no further information about them. How can we get a contradiction here?

Comment: As before, path connected components are open, for a locally path connected. And well, they are disjoint. The open cover formed by them, if infinite, wouldn't have a finite subcover.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [A countably compact, locally connected space has finitely many components](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/974245/a-countably-compact-locally-connected-space-has-finitely-many-components)

Comment: (I meant: knowing that [the path connected components of a locally path connected space are merely its connected components](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1820665)+2 more trivial remarks.)

Answer (score 2):

In a locally path connected space the path connected components are open. Thus the collection of the path connected components is an open cover of $X$ and from compactness of $X$ has a finite subcover. Now notice that the subcover has to be the cover itself as the path connected components are disjoint.

Comment: You should do the same argument with the path connected components, since those are the ones that need to be proven finite.

Comment: Oops I read connected components